# php - How to reverse a math equation based on a condition?

Tags: php, math

I have a unique and specific situation.

I have a search that searches volleyball players' stats. Once it queries and gets all the data, it then runs this:

```
$priority_query = $wpdb->get_results("
                    SELECT MAX(CAST(value AS UNSIGNED))
                    FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data
                    WHERE field_id = $field->id
                    ", ARRAY_N);

$field_max = $priority_query[0][0];

$priority_percentage = $field->priority / $priority_total;

$priority_rank = $priority_rank + round($priority_percentage * ($value_total/$field_max), 3);
}
$priority_rank = $priority_rank * 10;
```

That is to figure out the players ranking based of off the other players that are returned by the search. It works great. However, it essentially is all based on "bigger is better". So it gives a higher rank for height, jumping height. Stuff like that.

Now I've added two more search criteria that are based on speed (sprints). It's giving a higher rank to the slowest people because it's a greater number. I need it to be opposite (smaller is better) when one of the new fields is selected for the search.

I've tried all sorts of things, but can't figure it out. I tried changing the query from `MAX` to `MIN`, but the rankings went through the roof and were still showing the slowest as the best.

Does anybody know how I could do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated, this has been driving me crazy.

Thank you

**EDIT:**

I can't have negative numbers since the ranking it being displayed. Also, I can't have any static numbers since players can sign up whenever they want and add their stats which in turn modifies the search results.

A co-worker and I got it working just by switching thes around: `$value_total/$field_max` to `$field_max/$value_total` and `SELECT MAX` to `SELECT MIN` Then I added a conditional statement to figure it out properly.

A slight issue however is when you start mixing the two types of criteria together. It gets a little wonky, but still ranks in the proper order.

Comment: Hm... reversing a math equation. Btw, this is not a sarcastic comment, but when you do a certain mathematical equation, say an addition, then the reverse of that would be a substraction. Multiplying would be dividing. Is that what you're looking asking or looking for?

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and explain what isn't what you want from that code.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to probably just set the value to negative (`value * -1`). Then the higher the value, the lower the result. If this is for nothing but like a sort order/ranking, this would be fine. If you didn't want, or couldn't have, negative numbers, you could do $someReallyHighNumber-value to reverse the scale or even query for the max overall and then say maxOverall-value.

Comment: @Fred -ii- I didn't take that sarcastically, but yes, I tried changing all of the operators to their relative opposites.

Comment: *"A co-worker and I got it working just by switching thes around: $value_total/$field_max to $field_max/$value_total and SELECT MAX to SELECT MIN Then I added a conditional statement to figure it out properly."* --- I had a feeling that doing some form of reversal would make it work. Glad to hear you found a solution. @stinkysGTI